# How to run Node/Express App on port 3001, 3002 etc?

Tags: node.js, http, amazon-ec2, pm2, port-number

We are using 4 different express projects in a single server, running `pm2 start` cmd from each project root directory to start the app.

And using ec2 Linux server, added port `3000`, `3001` to inbound rules, both runs fine but not able to access API's through `3001`, and able access by 3000, what could be an Issue?

the same project running at `3000`, but not in `3001`, so we can confirm, there is no bug in our projects.

Tried at terminal `nodemon app` it runs fine but not accessed by `Postman` getting same error :

```
Could not get any response

There was an error connecting to http://ec2-x-x-amazonaws.com:3001/api/login.
```

how can we run multiple node/express projects in available/defined ports?

```
3001    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
3000    tcp 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 ✔
```

Some ports running without add as an inbound rule like 8088, 8089.

**pm2** status shows all ports are running fine.

[image]

The `pm2 list` is above and `id 8` have port number `3001`

Comment: in that case mostly check with `pm2 status` if the app is running which is expected to run in `3000`, and also check if its listning in `3000` only not any other port.

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty - port `3000` running fine, but `3001` does not run from `pm2 status`, how can I archive it?

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty - restarted all ports `pm2 restart all --watch`, now `3001` also running fine, but not able to access from postman, and did not get any error log from `pm2 logs`

Comment: make sure once again, you have added inbound and outbound rules,

Comment: @saikatchakrabortty added `3000` and `3001` at inbound rules but what can we update in outbound rules? accepting all ports there.

Comment: Through what host are you trying to access those ports? A public IP assigned to the instance or something else?

Comment: @cantuket - Yes, and public IP assigned to those ports.

Comment: To answer your previous question, yes, you should leave your out bound rules to ALL 0.0.0.0/0 unless you have a good reason not to

Comment: Can you show us a screen shot of what `pm2 list` prints?

Comment: @cantuket - updated `pm2 list`

Comment: @151291 are you able to access the port 3001 from inside the server? Like `curl -I localhost:3001` or similar. If you can, there is some other issue with your configuration.

Comment: @gargsms - I hit the above cmd inside server terminal, getting error response `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, X-Powered-By: Express` host is `ec2` instead of `localhost` because app running in the `ec2` hostname.

Comment: That seems fine. I am not sure what the issue is then. Port 3001 seems not accessible from outside the server. You should look more into your EC2 configuration. I don't think pm2 has anything to do with it.

Comment: How are you loading the app, the specific pm2 commands. Your status looks like it's the same app running. What happens if you try hitting the non-api routes at port 3001?

Comment: Also, try `netstat -ntlp | grep 3001` on the ec2 instance command line

Comment: @adamrights - Have 4 projects, all project has app.js I am running pm2 in each root directory. so not possible for non-api routes. and tried `netstat` cmd, getting good response `tcp  0  0  x.x.x.x:3001  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  32702/node /home/ec2`

Comment: So there is a  node process listening on 3001. Are the other 2 apps also working? Are they explicit in the ports they use? Maybe one is stealing 3001?

Comment: @adamrights - other ports are running and accessing from `postman` fine, all using different ports checked by `netstat -ntlp | grep node`

Comment: Hmm. So I think we'd need to see that api code. Other thoughts, maybe if you don't hit that endpoint with certain headers, cookies, etc...its behavior is to 404. The x-Powerered-By: Express tells you the nodejs server handled that 404.

Also, have you tried `https://` instead of `http://`

Comment: @adamrights - other running ports also showing `404` from terminal, the server does not have ssl. I am using header `Content-Type : application/json` like other ports.

Comment: This all looks like you just need to open port 3001 in your EC2 security group...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a port number issue, re-checked from server inbound rules, whether the port 3001 and 3002 etc added correctly with `custom TCP rule` and `source` must be `anywhere`. now runs fine.

```
ec2-Instances -> launch-wizard-1 -> right click -> edit inbound rules.
```

Answer (score 3):

NOTE: Not an answer necessarily, but these are some things I've screwed up before and this is the process I would use to troubleshoot...


**PM2 Configuration**

First check this to make sure you don't have any conflicts. 

*(As mentioned in comments please provide screen shot of `pm2 list` and even the, PM2 config files if possible)*

How are you running PM2, a single `ecosystem.json` config? Multiple `ecosystem.json` configs? Either way...

Make sure that each `app` has correctly specified properties...

- `script:`(start-up script)
- `cwd:` (working directory)
- Unique `name:` for each process
- If you're specifying your environment variables `env:` in the PM2 configuration make sure they are correctly set to `3000` and `3001` respectively.
- Make sure you haven't accidentally hardcoded both app to run on `3000` .i.e make sure these `env` configs are actually being used.

Another thing to note here is that if you update your PM2 config files a simple `pm2 restart` won't look for the new configuration. You will need to add the `--update-env` flag.

**Basic Port Web Server Test**


If the above checks on PM2 are fine then I would start narrowing things down further by eliminate node entirely for now. You could try something like this for a quick test of the accessibility of port 3001...

1. Stop all pm2 processes

`pm2 stop all`

2. Install Nginx

`sudo apt-get install nginx`

3. Edit default config file

`sudo nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/default` Or whatever editor you want

4. Configure server. Add to the top of file...

```js
 server {
      listen 3001;
      listen [::]:3001;
      location / {
          return 200 '3001 works!';
      }
  }
```

5. Restart Nginx

`sudo service nginx restart`



Now try to access the public IP at port 3001 and it should download a text file to your machine with *"3001 works!"*

If this works the issues is not EC2 or the related security groups, but rather your node servers.

Answer (score 2):

if your code looks like this

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port + '!');
});
```

you can change the port from the command that starts the server like so

```
PORT=8000 node index.js
```

for more exmaples check this out https://gist.github.com/indiesquidge/7fe1d8be1b973f782c97

You could also pass the port as an argument to your script using `process.argv`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = getPort();

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port + '!');
});

function getPort(){
    if(process.argv.length > 2){
        return process.argv[2];
    } else {
        return 3000;
    }
}
```

Comment: not able to change port number by using cmd `PORT=8000 node app.js` , still listens the defined port from `app.js`

Comment: could you please post your app.js code? at least the part where the server is started

Comment: @151291 i added another example, see if that helps